how to implement glide library in build.gradle.kts
Unexpected tokens (use ';' to separate expressions on the same line)

this is the error that i am getting while i am trying to implement Glide library in my app
I also tried to use
implementation(com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.16.0)

but the error still remains
Can someone tell me how to implement glide library or libraries in general.

try alt+enter on the code where it is showing error, and see what suggestions it is providing.

You are doing just a small mistake. You are using Groovy script syntax in a Kotlin Gradle file.
Use it like this
implementation("com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.16.0")


Tip

annotationProcessor("com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.16.0")

Make sure to include the annotationProcessor line for Glide's annotation processor. This is necessary if you use Glide's annotations for generating API (e.g., @GlideModule).
kapt("com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.16.0")

The kapt block with correctErrorTypes = true is optional but recommended for better error handling during annotation processing.

You can refer this link and scroll it down a little bit after that you can use how to use the library in maven, kotlin etc.
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.bumptech.glide/glide/4.16.0#gradle-short-kotlin

When using the build.kts.gradle format, you will have to use in the gradle file
implementation(libs.glide)
Then navigate to

libs.versions.toml

and paste the dependency there
[versions]
...
agp = "8.5.1"
glide = "4.16.0"
...

[libraries]

glide = { module = "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide", version.ref = "glide" }
...

